# Permissions to write onPremisesExtensionAttributes using MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm writeing Single-Page-Application and I'm trying to patch onPremisesExtensionAttributes using MS Graph in my own ms profile like this:

```
[PATCH] https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{my-user-id}
{
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes" : {
        "extensionAttribute10" : "test"
    }
}
```

But I receive an error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied",
        "message": "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-03-10T08:33:10",
            "request-id": "1f20871c-e9f2-46df-bdce-21157212ef7a",
            "client-request-id": "1f20871c-e9f2-46df-bdce-21157212ef7a"
        }
    }
}
```

My registered application has delegated permissions:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read
https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite
```

I tried update other properties like phone number and it works. Problem is only with extensionAttribute's.

What other privileges I need to update onPremisesExtensionAttributes in my own profile?

//UPDATE:

When I added User.ReadWrite.All privileges it works, but I don't want to allow edit users someone else profile. I want to allow to edit only his own profile.

Comment: not so sure, and I found `For an onPremisesSyncEnabled user, the source of authority for this set of properties is the on-premises and is read-only and is read-only` in the document. By the way, permissions are `User.ReadWrite, User.ManageIdentities.All, User.EnableDisableAccount.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All` for [this api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions).

Comment: Agree with @TinyWang you need Directory.ReadWrite.All to update extension attributes.

Comment: Adding Directory.ReadWrite.All didn't help

Comment: Can you check by adding the remaining premissions as mentioned above: User.ManageIdentities.All, User.EnableDisableAccount.All, User.ReadWrite.All

Comment: I added User.ReadWrite.All (application privileges) and it works, but I don't want to allow edit users someone else profile. I want to allow to edit only his own profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned above in the comments, using the remaining permission like User.ReadWrite.All (application privileges) it has worked, not sure we can do it without that permission.

To Restrict member user's permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/users-default-permissions#restrict-member-users-default-permissions

Hope this helps.